# How to authenticate against keycloak using axios?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, axios

I want to query an internal API. When I access it via the browser it redirects me to a keycloak login page where I put my user credentials and get redirected back to the API getting the result I want.

Now I want to do the same from a script. and fail.

When I query the API

```
axios.get(api_url)
```

I get the html login page back.

Now what?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not clear I need to know more to help.

Comment: well. when I do it manually in the browser I open http://somecomapnyurl.com/api and I get redirected to http://auth.mycomapny.com/login where I am asked for my personal credentials (username, password) when I enter them correctly I get re-redirected back to http://somecomapnyurl.com/api and can see its output. Now I want to do the same from my express router instance using axios.get() which also redirects me to the login url but I don't know how to provide the user credentials

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't provide the user credentials this way. Keycloak, or the OAuth2 workflow, redirects you to an URL which is to be opened by the browser which will then forward your user to the login form. As far as I know, there is no way how a "backend" application could provide user credentials.

If you are using Axios for a JavaScript-based frontend application, an alternative way could be to read the redirect url and then update `window.location.href = <redirect url from Keycloak>`.